# PHP Update SQL Con BindParam - NO FUNCIONA

Tags: php, mysqli, php7, php8

tengo un problema, estoy implementando un codigo en PHP que debe actualizar valores, entonces tengo que utilizar MySQLi orientado a objetos y con bind_param, tengo php 8.1 y no se por qué las de select e insert me funcionan pero esta no, no afecta a las filas. Os dejo el código

**Esta es mi tabla:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esta es la sentencia SQL:**

```
private const SQL_UPDATE_USER = "UPDATE usuarios SET idUserSession = ?, namePassword = ?, listProducts = ? WHERE nameUser = ?";
```

**Este es el codigo PHP de la consulta:**

```
try {
   # Objeto Usuario (dni, nombre, apellidos, preferencias)
   $user = new User('a','b','c','d');
   #   SE PREPARA OBJETO DE CONEXION
   $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($this::SQL_UPDATE_USER);
   #   SE PARAMETRIZA
   $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $user->idUserSession, $user->namePassword, $user->listProducts, $user->userName);
   #   SE EJECUTA LA SENTENCIA
   $stmt->execute();
   #   RESULTADO
   $res = $stmt->affected_rows;
   #   DEPENDIENDO DEL RESULTADO SE RETORNA
   if($res == 1){
      #   SE MUESTRA
      echo "ACTUALIZADO";
   }
   #   SI NO
   else{
      echo "NO SE PUDO ACTUALIZAR");
   }
} catch (\Throwable $th) {
    #   SE PINTA
    print_r($th);
}
```

Pero al ejecutar me dice que ***no se ha actualizado***, alguien puede indicarme qué es lo que tengo mal y como resolverlo? Realmente no caigo...

Saludos.

Comment: Y supongo que la conexion es correcta, vamos, que no esta apuntando a una base de datos distinta... podrias probar con un `echo $stmt->error;` despues del execute, a ver si te muestra algo

Comment: No, mejor borramos comentarios y seguimos aqui... el otro dia descubrí que los chats son eternos, no se puede borrar nada y quedan alli para siempre, y google los indexa... privacidad 0

Comment: Vale los he borrado ya, realmente no se que puede ser... no tiene sentido

Comment: Prueba hardcodeando los valores en lugar de sacarlos del objeto $user, y si funciona ves poniendolos de nuevo uno a uno hasta dar con el problematico

Comment: Vale ya está, no habia escrito bien una de las propiedades del objeto.. el sueño me está jugando malas pasadas. Elimino la pregunta?

Comment: si, mejor :-)  eliminala